# Counting intersection of binary values

Tags: algorithm, scala

In below algorithm I'm counting the amount of times the char "1" appears and is also in same position within each String.

```
    def coeff3(a: String, b: String): Float = {
    val aArray = a.toArray
    val bArray = b.toArray
    var i, intersectCounter = 0;
    def coeff1: Int = {
      if ((aArray(i).asDigit == 1) && (bArray(i).asDigit == 1)) {
        intersectCounter += 2
      }
      i = i + 1
      if ((aArray.size) == i)
        intersectCounter
      else
        coeff1
    }

    coeff1

  }                                               //> coeff3: (a: String, b: String)Float

  val str1 = "10110"                              //> str1  : String = 10110
  val str2 = "10111"                              //> str2  : String = 10111

    coeff3(str1 , str2)  > res2: Float = 6.0
```

As can see `coeff3(str1 , str2)` returns 6. Is there a more functional approach to solving this instead of this recursive method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to convert them to Ints and sum their pairwise products like so:

```
scala> (str1,str2).zipped.map(_.asDigit * _.asDigit).sum * 2
res19: Int = 6
```

Here's another way:

```
scala> str1.zip(str2).count( _ == ('1','1') ) * 2
res77: Int = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this general approach where the input is a list of strings,

```
implicit class RichCoeffs(val xss: List[String]) extends AnyVal {

  def coeff3(key: Char = '1'): Float = {
    if (xss.size < 2) 0F
    else
      xss.transpose.map{ xs => xs.forall { _ == key } }.count{ _ == true } * 2F
  }

}
```

and so

```
List("10110","10111").coeff3()
res: Float = 6.0
```

In fact

```
List("10110","10111").transpose
res: List[List[Char]] = List(List(1, 1), 
                             List(0, 0), 
                             List(1, 1), 
                             List(1, 1), 
                             List(0, 1))
```

Thus we need to check for each list that all the elements equal to the key character; then we count how many satisfy such a requirement, and double the amount as required in the question.

Let us now consider

```
val strs = List("10110", "10111", "10100")
```

Hence

```
strs.coeff3()
res: Float = 4.0

strs.coeff3('3')
res: Float = 0.0

strs.coeff3('1')
res: Float = 4.0

strs.coeff3('0')
res: Float = 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to combine the two strings and then use `count` to find the number of times `1` is in the same position.

```
scala> str1.zip(str2).count(t => t._1 == '1' && t._2 == '1') * 2
res11: Int = 6
```